# PHPExcel setAutoSize for merged cells

Tags: php, phpexcel

#### Code without merge

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, 
        "test test test test test test test test");
$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
```

[image]

#### Code with merge

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, 
        "test test test test test test test test");
//this breaks the width calculation
$sheet->mergeCells('A1:B1');
$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
```

[image]

As far as I understand, there is no standard way to set auto size for merged cells. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 6):

You could calculate the column widths before merging the cells using `->calculateColumnWidths()`, and then `->setAutoSize(false)` to make sure that they are not calculated again. The code could
look something like this:

```
// Set the data in the cells
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($sheet, null, 'A1');

// Calculate the column widths
foreach(range('A', 'E') as $columnID) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateColumnWidths();

// Set setAutoSize(false) so that the widths are not recalculated
foreach(range('A', 'E') as $columnID) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(false);
}

// Merge cells
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A1:A5");
```

Answer (score 1):

i personnaly used the size of the value to adapt the size of the cell :

```
$value =  $sheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();
$width = mb_strwidth ($value); //Return the width of the string
$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth($width);
```

Beware if you have made a  `->setAutoSize(true)` on the column that you want to modify you need to put it at false before doing any modifications :

`$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(false);`