# PHPExcel column A:C wont auto size width

Tags: php, phpexcel

So I have implemented this code, to generate my excel:

```php
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER); //Default = whole workbook center vertical
$tsc = array_keys($data);
for ($i=0; $i < count($tsc); $i++) {
    if ($i != 0) {
        $objPHPExcel->createSheet($i);
    }
    //Active sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($i);

    $tsc_data = explode(";", $tsc[$i]); //[0] = tsc name - [1] = tsc id
    //Columns merging
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle(substr($tsc_data[0],0,30))
    ->mergeCells('A'.$table_row.':A'.($table_row+3))
    ->mergeCells('B'.$table_row.':B'.($table_row+3))
    ->mergeCells('C'.$table_row.':C'.($table_row+3))
    //merge area
    ->mergeCells('D'.$table_row.':H'.($table_row+2))
    //Adding cell text
    ->SetCellValue('A'.$table_row.'', 'Sr. No.ddddddddddddddddddddddd')
    ->SetCellValue('B'.$table_row.'', 'Component namedddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd')
    ->SetCellValue('C'.$table_row.'', 'Featuresddddddddddddddddddddddd')
    ->SetCellValue('D'.$table_row.'', $tsc_data[0])
    ->SetCellValue('D'.($table_row+3), 'HW Detailsddddddddddddddddddddddd')
    ->SetCellValue('E'.($table_row+3), 'Test Case ID/ Test Stepsddddddddddddddddddddddd')
    ->SetCellValue('F'.($table_row+3), 'Expectedddddddddddddddddddddddd')
    ->SetCellValue('G'.($table_row+3), 'Resultddddddddddddddddddddddd')
    ->SetCellValue('H'.($table_row+3), 'Remarkddddddddddddddddddddddd');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$table_row.':H'.($table_row+3))->applyFromArray($bold_text_12);
    foreach(range('A','H') as $columnID) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
            ->setAutoSize(true);
    }
}
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

And as you can see I do have the part which auto size the columns

```php
foreach(range('A','H') as $columnID) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
        ->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

This works but only for columns `D:H` not `A:C`, and I Dont know why?

You can see here that the columns have auto sized when I open the xml file, but not for `A:C`

[image]

Can any of you see what is blocking this, because to me it should work, but dosn't?

**EDIT**

I can see that the merging of `A:C` makes the auto sizeing stop, so if i remove them, the lines does auto size again...

```php
//These lines
->mergeCells('A'.$table_row.':A'.($table_row+3))
->mergeCells('B'.$table_row.':B'.($table_row+3))
->mergeCells('C'.$table_row.':C'.($table_row+3))
//Do I insert the text into the cells right????
->SetCellValue('A'.$table_row.'', 'Sr. No.ddddddddddddddddddddddd')
->SetCellValue('B'.$table_row.'', 'Component namedddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd')
->SetCellValue('C'.$table_row.'', 'Featuresddddddddddddddddddddddd')
```

NOTE: `$table_row` is default = 1, so `'A'.$table_row.':A'.($table_row+3)` is `A1:A4`

Comment: Please read the `EDIT` found the lines which causes the blocking of auto size

Comment: PHPExcel was deprecated in 2017, you should probably use its successor [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). That being said, you might find the answer to your problem here: [PHPExcel setAutoSize for merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333143/phpexcel-setautosize-for-merged-cells)

Comment: @slashroot I know, the reason I use `PHPExcel` is due to the PHP version I run `PHP 7.1` and can't upgrade at the moment. But I made a solution for this tho :)

Comment: I understand, was just mentioning it in case you weren't aware. Glad the link helped you find the solution you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, so I've put the merging part at the bottom of my code now, and right before I do that, I auto size all columns, and turn it off again, so the merging won't recalculate the width:

```php
foreach(range('A','H') as $columnID) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateColumnWidths();

// Set setAutoSize(false) so that the widths are not recalculated
foreach(range('A','H') as $columnID) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(false);
}
//Columns merging (HAS TO BE AT THE END ELSE AUTO SEIZE WONT WORK)
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle(substr($tsc_data[0],0,30))
->mergeCells('A'.$table_row.':A'.($table_row+3))
->mergeCells('B'.$table_row.':B'.($table_row+3))
->mergeCells('C'.$table_row.':C'.($table_row+3))
//merge area
->mergeCells('D'.$table_row.':H'.($table_row+2));
```